# How to reformat node.js fatal error message to one line?

Tags: node.js, error-handling, hekad

I want to add nodejs error messages to a `nodejs -> file.log -> hekad -> elasticsearch -> kibana` stack and I'm facing the issue that heka apparently expects a single error message to be newline terminated, while for fatal errors it has multiple lines, e.g.:

`test.js:5
a();
^
ReferenceError: a is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (test.js:5:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:902:3`

I'm trinking of adding code like to all my scripts:

```
process.stderr.oldwrite = process.stderr.write;

process.stderr.write = function (m) {
    // so that stuff like EventEmitter memory leak gets to 1 line too
    process.stderr.oldwrite(m.trim().replace(/\n/g, '\\n') + '\n');
};

process.on('uncaughtException', function(error) {
    process.stderr.write(error.stack);
});
```

This way the output will be on one line clearly meaning it's about a single error, but I'm wondering if it's the correct approach to the problem?